# How to extract entities with nlpjs v4?

Tags: node.js, nlp

I'm having difficulties to extract the entities with the 'nlpjs' v4. seems like the documentation is only for v3.

```
  const { NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');

  const nlpManager = new NlpManager({
    languages: ["en"],
    forceNER: true,
  });

  nlpManager.addDocument("en", "hi, my name is %name%", "name");
  nlpManager.addAnswer("en", "name", "hello there %name%");

  await nlpManager.train();
  nlpManager.save();
  let response = await nlpManager.process("en", "my name is John Doe");
  console.log(response);
```

It could be classified correctly, but the entities is always empty.

```
  classifications: [ { intent: 'name', score: 1 } ],
  intent: 'name',
  score: 1,
  sourceEntities: [],
  entities: [],
```

There are no documentation for the extraction with the v4. How could I use the NER in the v4?